# Circular import error only when importing specific function

Tags: python, scapy, python-packaging

I am using scapy 2.4.5 and am trying to use the UDP class.

```
from scapy.all import UDP
```

runs with no issue, but I can not use the IDE to go to declaration. If I click on it shows no declaration found. However if I use

```
from scapy.layers.inet import UDP
```

I can then go to the declaration and see the class and associated code. but when I run it I get the following error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AnsweringMachine' from partially initialized module 'scapy.ansmachine' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

There are no other imports and this is VERY basic

```
from scapy.layers.inet import UDP


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    new_udp_packet = UDP()
    print(new_udp_packet)
```

expected output

```
WARNING: No IPv4 address found on en5 !
WARNING: No IPv4 address found on ap1 !
WARNING: more No IPv4 address found on awdl0 !
WARNING: Calling str(pkt) on Python 3 makes no sense!
b'\x005\x005\x00\x08\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy fix:

```
import scapy.all  # makes sure everything gets imported in the right order
from scapy.layers.inet import UDP
```

Of course you'll then have to make sure the `scapy.all` import remains first in the file.

<del>However, I'd recommend looking into an IDE that can resolve imports through the `scapy.all` file... :)</del>

Since `scapy.layers.all` (which is what `scapy.all` imports) dynamically chooses the layer modules to load via `scapy.conf.load_layers`, it can unfortunately not work with code completion that doesn't evaluate code.

Comment: which IDE is that because this is with both visual studio code and pycharm

Comment: Why does this solution work I am so confused...

Comment: Because the `scapy.all` module imports things in a correct order, so there are no circular imports.